# JavaScript Regular Expressions for Phone Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, phone-number

I need help with a line of regular expression which validates phone number and it goes like this:
`tel:/^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[\.\-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[\.\-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[\.\-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/`

And these are the formats it validates:

> *555 5555*
>   *1-555-555-5555*
>   *1.555.555.5555*
>   *15555555555 extension 555*
>   *15555555555 ext. 555*
>   *15555555555 # 555*
>   *15555555555 x. 555*

I want to validate numbers like:

> +263 772 485 384
>   773456284
>   0773456284

mostly international numbers

Comment: While I can certainly relate to the temptation, I don't think all of this should be in one regex.

Comment: What about splitting it into different regexes?

Comment: @YatharthROCK - That's what I meant. This should be split up into multiple regex's with clearly defined functions. Trying to do it all in one regex is just asking for a headache.

Comment: You may be better off stripping anything that is not an digit and then doing a count. Then deal it that way. Before you strip the non-digits, look for clues about what country it might be. For instance, +1 = US, +91 = India, ^1*\d{10}$ would be US

Comment: Yep. Unless you're trying to win something like the [1K contest](http://js1k.com/), you're better off doing what @JosephSilber said. Saves debugging time for you and whoever is unlucky enough to have to reuse your code.

Comment: I think you should really accept my answer of you feel it was helpful or atleast well-researched or useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, split that big chunk of regex. You might want to use your language's `verbose` option if it has one. I split most of for you:

```
Telephone Numbers (should be 'orred'):
  \+?\d{3}(?:\ \d{3,4})+
  \d[-.]\d{3}[-.]\d{3}[-.]\d{4}
  \d{9,11}

Extensions (should be 'anded' with the previous regexes)
  (\ ext(?:\.|ension)(?:\ \#)?\ \d{3,4})?
```